# How to use recv function without using while(true)?

Tags: sockets, printf, do-while

I am trying to write a simple client server application, where I am sending data from client & receiving that it in server side, I need to store that data into the common buffer and later on create a file for each client and print that common buffer data into file.

```
    do  
    {
       int numByte=recv(server,buffer,bufsize,0);
       if ( numByte == -1 )
         {
           printf("ERROR : could not receive bytes \n");
         }
        //buffer[numByte]='\0';
        //bzero(buffer,10000);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    strcpy(globalBuffer[i],buffer);
        //cout<<"Global_buffer:"<<globalBuffer[i];          
    }


    for(int j =0;j<10;j++){
    fprintf(fp, "%s",globalBuffer[j]);

    }
    //strcpy(buffer,globalBuffer[fileNum]);
    fflush(fp);
}while(!isExit);
```

The above one is the code snippet where I am trying to copy the buffer data into globalBuffer and later on printing that globalBuffer data into file. I am supposed to print only 10 string messages for each file but as I have do-while loop, and that is never ending loop the `fprintf(fp, "%s",globalBuffer[j])` it isn't ending because of do-while loop and if I try to store the buffer data outside a do-while loop it isn't possible as do-while loop never ends.

Is there any ways to avoid do-while loop and instead of that is there any flags in recv() function which can act as do-while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're supposed to exit the loop if `recv()` returns zero, which means the peer has disconnected, and also in most cases when it returns -1, indicating an error. Surely you've seen this?

Comment: @Shivakumar Hard to tell what that means, but you should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here.